In Microsoft 365 admin centre, is there a way to delete the data downloaded by OneDrive and Teams apps on that a mobile device?
In Exchange admin centre > Recipients > Mailboxes > <User's Name> > General > Manage mobile devices, there is the option of 'Account Only Remote Wipe Device' that wipe the emails downloaded in Outlook on the selected mobile device. But is there a way to delete the data downloaded by OneDrive and Teams apps on that device?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am looking for a way to delete a user's data which resides on their mobile devices when they leave the company.
With the above-mentioned option, Outlook data gets wiped from a mobile device, but OneDrive and Teams data remain. Is there an option to wipe OneDrive and Teams data as well?

How are these devices enrolled? You're looking in Exchange, which, of course, only worked on Exchange data. You'll need to use whichever management tool you're using to manage enrollments on these devices (Intune?) to remove all corporate data.

They are not enrolled in a manual way or something. They just appear in the place I mentioned above when a user adds his account to him mobile phone.

The best solution is to use a Mobile Device Manager (MDM), such as Microsoft Intune. This will allow full or partial device management so you can remotely manage apps and company information. It appears that you can use Intune whether you have Microsoft 365, on-premises Active Directory, or just upload a CSV with users and groups.
Microsoft Intune Managing Identities
However, the device may already be using the Basic Mobility and Security features provided by Microsoft 365. This might be all you need to do exactly what you want.
Wipe a Mobile Device in Basic Mobility and Security - Microsoft
From the Microsoft 365 Admin Center, go to Devices > Active Devices. You may find the device in the Fully Managed or App Managed tab. Click the device you want to wipe, and select Remove company data.

With no MDM or Basic Mobility and Security in place, You may be able to delete the files in OneDrive. You can access the user's files from the Microsoft 365 Admin Center > Users > Active Users > [user] > OneDrive. Click Create link to files, which will give you a link to that user's OneDrive files, and you can delete the files. I'm assuming that if the mobile device connects to OneDrive it will sync, and all the files will be deleted.

I cannot find something specifically similar for Teams without using some type of MDM. Teams does have an Admin Center, and registers devices. It is reasonable to suspect there may be a delete option here, but I unfortunately don't use Teams and cannot find any specific option to delete Teams data remotely without MDM.
As with all device management, you should test any of these options first, to make sure it works as expected. Note that for any remote device management to work, the device has to come online to receive the deletion requests. However, there do exist Conditional Access policies that require certain sign-in frequencies to access resources.
Conditional Access adaptive session lifetime

After I accepted your answer, I found out that there is an admin centre for Teams. But looking around, my eyes haven't fall on something useful.
And it looks like I can't post a screenshot in a comment.
